# edit node attribute in view

Tags: views, nodes

In Drupal 7, is there a way to edit nodes from a view? For example, could I add a checkbox or drop down menu for each node in the view to set a particular attribute of that node?

Comment: I was going to suggest your taking a look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_D4z4Bw6iw It turns out it's the same module suggested by Neo. I'd still recommend reviewing it, as it will give you a good kickstart.

Comment: Nice tutorial. Definitely worth looking at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [EditableViews](https://drupal.org/project/editableviews) module should serve your purpose well. Here is part of the module's project page:

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited. Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save' button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.